# Unable to install EmguCV via NuGet in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, installation, nuget-package, emgucv

I wanted to play around with Emgu.CV but I still fail installing it.

I created a new C# project, right click to Reference >> Manage NuGet Packages. Entering "Emgu" in the search field, you'll find EmguCV.

[image]

Clicking "Install" I get this output:

[image]

That also happens, when I try to use older versions.

Using EMGU.CV - its the same.

Does anybody has an idea?

Thank you.

Comment: It seems the current EmguCV 3.1.0.1 not supported on your current project, please have a look at this: 
http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page and it mentions 3.1.0-r16.12 added UWP support for Windows Phone commercial license, you can go to Package Manager Console to using the command: Install-Package Emgu.CV -Version 3.3.0.2824 to have a try. I tested it in my side and got another incompatible error, if you also meet this same issue, please report this issue to the EmguCV owner in here: https://github.com/emgucv/emgucv/issues to seek for a more professional support, thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I can to the same point. Now, using 3.2.0 works quite finde for me.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't found an answer using NuGet. Just downloaded the version 3.2.0 (not the latest version, this didn't work in my case) and installed it manually. Just got to this side http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Emgu_CV and follow the point "Download and installation".

Comment: it just a reminder, you can mark this reply as answer, that will help others to easier search this helpful information. :)

Comment: I've tried with framework 4.6.2 and 4.7.2 and WPF and Winforms, all without success. The only way it worked after your answer was to not use newest Emgu.CV 4.5 but version 4.4 by using default nuget Manager in Visual Studio 2019.